Unable to install Ubuntu Security Guide on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
per my undertandin Ubuntu 24.04 supports USG (https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/disa-stig/installation), however I getting "Ubuntu Security Guide is not available for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
user@device:~$ sudo pro enable usg
[sudo] password for user: 
One moment, checking your subscription first
Ubuntu Security Guide is not available for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat).
Could not enable Ubuntu Security Guide.``` 

